# Suddenly maven does not compile

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

```
C:\Users\nanjiang.jx>mvn -version
    Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-07 03:16:01+0800)
    Java version: 1.6.0_45
    Java home: D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre
    Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: GBK
    OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "amd64" Family: "windows"
C:\Users\nanjiang.jx>java -version
    java version "1.7.0_60"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

I've been developing in Java using maven for a few days.The project to others compile ok.

Today,i use a new pc and setting env like above.

when i typed mvn eclipse:eclipse,jar was downloaded,but it's not append to .classpath.

```
c:\idlecenter>call mvn clean eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=tru
    e
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] Reactor build order:
    [INFO]   idlecenter-all
    [INFO]   idlecenter-client
    [INFO]   idlecenter-dal
    [INFO]   idlecenter-server
    [INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'eclipse'.
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building idlecenter-all
    [INFO]    task-segment: [clean, eclipse:eclipse]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
    [INFO] Preparing eclipse:eclipse
    [INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
    [INFO] [eclipse:eclipse {execution: default-cli}]
    [INFO] Not running eclipse plugin goal for pom project
    [INFO] Using Eclipse Workspace: null
    [INFO] Adding default classpath container: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAIN
    ER
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building idlecenter-client
    [INFO]    task-segment: [clean, eclipse:eclipse]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
    [INFO] Deleting directory I:\idlecenter\idlecenter-client\target
    [INFO] Preparing eclipse:eclipse
    [INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
    [INFO] [eclipse:eclipse {execution: default-cli}]
    [INFO] Using Eclipse Workspace: null
    [INFO] Adding default classpath container: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAIN
    ER
    [ERROR] An error occurred during dependency resolution of the following artifact
    :
        com.ning:compress-lzf:0.6.0
    Caused by: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata fil
    e for artifact 'com.ning:compress-lzf:jar': Cannot find parent: org.sonatype.oss
    :oss-parent for project: com.ning:compress-lzf:bundle:0.6.0 for project com.ning
    :compress-lzf:bundle:0.6.0
      com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:0.6.0
```

Comment: To start with, you shouldn't be using the maven-eclipse-plugin; it's been outdated for years. Use m2eclipse instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well .... the parent POM ('org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:2') exists in the main Maven repos.  So perhaps there was a transient problem downloading it.

Take a look in your local maven repo (e.g. "~/.m2/repository/...") to see if the parent POM is there, and check to see if Maven has downloaded a corrupted copy.  (Does that POM file look the same as what you see on [this page](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.sonatype.oss%7Coss-parent%7C2%7Cpom)?

If it is corrupt, you can try blowing away the ".../org.sonatype.oss/..." subtree and run Maven again.  If you are still seeing Maven failures, then maybe you need to check how you have configured your upstream repository details, etc.

Comment: Thanks，the lib com.ning:compress-lzf:0.6.0 was not exits in  my repos. Others work because they have the lib in local. So my new pc .....